# How does RTC source control keep track of projects?

Tags: clearcase, rtc

Does RTC source control store a file to keep track of projects. In clearcase there is a copyarea.db file, is there something similar in RTC source control ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copyarea.db is a CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client, so not just "ClearCase") mechanism, described in "[About the .copyarea.dat and .copyarea.db files](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119280)" as:

> Each CCRC or CCWeb view root directory (the directory tree where the files from the VOB are downloaded into the local view workspace) contains a `.copyarea.dat` and a `.copyarea.db` files.
>
> - The .copyarea.dat file is used to detect if changes have been made to the loaded files to determine if they are in a hijacked state.
> - The `.copyarea.db` file is created in each directory of a CCRC or CCWeb view which contains a list of files that are loaded in the view as well as metadata about the files.

So **no**, RTC doesn't have a jazz file in each directories.
It has a **`.jazz5` directory** at the root of your local workspace. It contains all the necessary metadata regarding the remote "repository workspace" state compared to the local workspace "sandbox".